# Android JsonReader getting specific object json as json

Tags: android, json, geometry, jsonreader

I'm parsing a very large json file with jsonreader as an inputstream.
This json has a geometry object and on this specific object i would like to get the json itself instead of parsing it's individual values.

This is because its easier to convert a json string to a working geometry than it's individual values with this function...

ST_GeomFromGeoJSON();

Is there any way of getting the underlying json of an object when using a jsonreader?

if (tag.equals("geometry")) {
    reader.beginObject();